# 12.04 POSTFIX openDKIM no DKIM signature

Tags: 12.04, configuration, postfix, dkim

I followed the instructions in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134725/setup-dkim-domainkeys-for-ubuntu-postfix-and-mailman)
here's my postfix main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

myhostname = 2mm.biz                                     
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = 2mm.biz, 2mm.compute-1.internal, localhost.compute-1.internal, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 54.243.206.201/32
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
luser_relay = ubuntu@localhost
local_recipient_maps =
virtual_alias_domains = 2mm.biz
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
#added below for DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
#EOF
```

And here is my opendkim.conf

```
Syslog                  yes
LogWhy                  yes
UMask                   022
UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
Domain                  2mm.biz
KeyFile                 /etc/opendkim/20121002.private
Selector                20121002
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
Mode                    sv
#SubDomains             no

KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
```

I'm only using one domain so I left SubDomains commented out. When I check with 
http://www.brandonchecketts.com/emailtest.php it says that there are no domainkeys or DKIM signature.  I updated my DNS with my public key. This is on an amazon EC2 64 bit Ubuntu micro instance. I used sendmail command to test the signatures.

I'm to sure where else to look for a solution.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my own answer.  the messages in /var/log/mail.log were instrumental in tracking down what was wrong.  I'm still new to Linux, that was a tough lesson learned.

my problem was that in opendkim.conf I specified settings for:

1. Domian
2. KeyFile
3. Selector

And also

1. KeyTable
2. SigningTable

I removed the tables and the emails were signed from all emails in my domain.  That is after i restarted opendkim and postfix.